# Unable to parse JSON using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, http, http-headers, retrofit

I am using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to hit an api. I need to get both Json and header response. So my interface method is like this. So in Response type Object I get response header from `response.getHeaders()`. But when I try to get the json response from `response.getBody()`, I don't get a proper response. I need help in fetching and parsing the json response from the Response object :-(

```
@GET("/api/hello/categories")
retrofit.client.Response getData();
```

Comment: Do you need it to be synchronous call or can it be async? I have a solution if it can async.

Answer (score 1):

`getBody()` doesn't return a String directly, you'll have to convert it yourself if you don't want to user Retrofit's built converters.

[This link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/243/files) should be a simple way to grab the String from the response, and you can parse it accordingly.